# Getting HTML link using Internet Explorer with VBA Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

Automating an Internet Explorer process by using VBA Excel.

I am trying to get the first link in this classname 'datacell' with the `th scope=row` in html using the first 'a href' tag as my needed link.

Correct link is black circled but the result is the red circled one
[image]

VBA code:

```vb
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
With appIE
    .Visible = False
    .Visible = True
    Set doc = appIE.document
    For Each li In doc.getElementsByClassName("list")
        checkIfAttachment = li.innerHTML
                    
        If InStr(checkIfAttachment, "No matches found") Then
            ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = "Not in SFDC"
        Else
            Set childLi = Nothing
            For Each childLi In doc.getElementsByClassName(" dataCell  ")
                link = childLi.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
                'first link is the one we want
            Next childLi
                        
            link = Replace(link, "https://sample.com", "")
            link = Replace(link, "?srPos=0&srKp=00P", "")
            .navigate baseSFDCDownloadLink & link
            Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
```

Comment: you don't need a loop for "datacell" . I'm not familiar with vba but something like this could work . "link = doc.getElementsByClassName(" dataCell  ")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)"

Comment: Please don't post pictures of html. You can use [edit] and its associated toolbar to find the icon `<>` which will allow you to insert and format html.

Comment: @pfndesign thank you so much! this worked out for me. :)

Comment: @QHarr hello thank you for the reminder. this is my first time to try the site anyway.

Comment: @itspapap I'm glad it's worked for you. i posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a loop for "datacell". I'm not familiar with VBA but something like this could work .

```
link = doc.getElementsByClassName(" dataCell ")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a `td` rather than `th` element then specify `th` e.g. with `type` css selector (adding class as well)

```
.document.querySelector("th.dataCell").href
```